# How do I describe drugging?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, style

I’m supposed to write a scene where someone drugs her husband for sexual purposes. But I don’t happen to know how that works. Does she slip drugs into his food or drink? What would be the condition of the victim? Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: so…. alcohol?

https://drugfree.org/learn/drug-and-alcohol-news/alcohol-most-common-date-rape-drug-law-enforcement-officials-say/

Comment: The methods and outcome are going to greatly depend on exactly what she uses, which will depend on exactly what outcome she wants.

Comment: If you're going to be writing about date-rape, I recommend you read the answers to [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/35265/23927).

Comment: It seems like this depends on the genre; presumably it'll be pretty different if you're writing a crime novel vs. erotica.

Answer (score 0):

...wife pours two glasses of wine and give him his. After a few minutes, she starts to giggle and tease him. "It's going to be fun tonight, I just put the magic pill into your drink; it's your move," she says, reaching out undoing his shirt button.